# register broadcastreceiver outside activity

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, android-broadcast

I want to add reminder functionality to my Application.
I have Activity with a Button `"Remind in 5 minutes"`. When I press this Button method `setReminderInMinutes` calls and in 5 minutes I will get a `Dialog Fragment`.

```
public void setReminderInMinutes(int timeInMinutes){
        BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent){

                    ReasonsNonDeliveryDlgFragment cityDlg = ReasonsNonDeliveryDlgFragment.newinstance();
                    cityDlg.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), CityDlgFragment.TAG);
                    ((Vibrator)getSystemService(VIBRATOR_SERVICE)).vibrate(800);
                    context.unregisterReceiver(this);                
            }
        };
        this.registerReceiver(receiver, new IntentFilter("somemessage"));
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("somemessage"), 0 );
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
        manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000*60*timeInMinutes, pintent);
    }
```

It works well until I stay on this Activity, but when I press back Button Activity destroys, `onReceive` method never fire and I receive exception:

```
     " android.app.IntentReceiverLeaked: Activity MyActivity has leaked    
     IntentReceiver MyActivity$1@42136488 that was originally registered   
     here. Are you missing a call to unregisterReceiver()?"
```

So, is there anyway to register `BroadcastReceiver` outside my Activity?
P.S. I have tried to register it in manifest file:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ReminderReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="name"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

But still nothing works. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You can register the broadcast receiver in the manifest file.

Comment: I have tried to do that, but onReceive method still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case it will not work because in manifest file you given the action as `"name"` but while creating intent you given the action as `"somemessage"`. So how it works. Give the same action name in manifest and intent.

Change your code like below

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ReminderReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="some_action"/>
     </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

And in setReminder() method

```
 PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast( this, 0, new Intent("some_action"), 0 );
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
        manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000*60*timeInMinutes, pintent)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to register reciever outside of Activity - register it inside manifest of application. In you case it should look like following:

```
<receiver android:name=".receivers.ReminderReceiver" >
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="somemessage" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Important to set `name` in `<intent-filter>` same as action of your `Intent` inside sended broadcast.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
super.onResume();

   // Register mMessageReceiver to receive messages.
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mMessageReceiver,
     new IntentFilter("my-event"));
}

// handler for received Intents for the "my-event" event 
private BroadcastReceiver mMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
   // Extract data included in the Intent
   String message = intent.getStringExtra("message");
   Log.d("receiver", "Got message: " + message);
 }
};

@Override
protected void onPause() {
   // Unregister since the activity is not visible
   LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mMessageReceiver);
   super.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to pass a reference of BroadCastReceiver to pending intent. You can also pass the reference of your activity so that it will be called for you when the pending intent goes of.

If you want to use BroadCastReceiver outside of your activity you can declare it in manifest like this

```
<receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
          android:exported="true">
</receiver>
```

Then in your activity do this to register it with alarm manager

```
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(this, MyReceiver.class), 0 );
        AlarmManager manager = (AlarmManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE));
        manager.set(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() + 1000*60*timeInMinutes, pintent);
```